# how to show a gzip encoded html string into an iframe src?

Tags: php, html, gzip, mime-types

**how to show a gzip encoded html string into an iframe src?**

this is working well there:

```
<?php echo 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8, '.htmlspecialchars($html_string); ?>
```

it renders like:

```html
<iframe src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8, <p><img alt="" src="http://www.condominiosc.com.br/media/k2/items/cache/c5e04af61668174cb3944eb774f111ed_XL.jpg" style="width:90%" /></p> <p>O distrato na compra de im&oacute;veis, ao lado dos atrasos nas entregas de unidades na planta, &eacute; um dos principais problemas que afetam as rela&ccedil;&otilde;es entre consumidores e construtoras e incorporadoras no Brasil. Tramita no Congresso Nacional um projeto de lei que regulamenta a &ldquo;desist&ecirc;ncia&rdquo; do contrato de compra de im&oacute;vel. Uma s&eacute;rie de propostas se arrastam nas duas casas legislativas, mas teve um passo importante recentemente. A Comiss&atilde;o de Assuntos Econ&ocirc;micos (CAE) do Senado aprovou&nbsp;emendas ao PLC 68/2018, que fixa direitos e deveres das partes nos casos de rescis&atilde;o de contratos de aquisi&ccedil;&atilde;o de im&oacute;veis em regime de incorpora&ccedil;&atilde;o imobili&aacute;ria ou loteamento. Agora, o tema ser&aacute; avaliado no Plen&aacute;rio do Senado.</p> <p>Ainda que questionado por parte dos senadores, &eacute; ineg&aacute;vel que se trata de importante avan&ccedil;o, na medida em que regra consequ&ecirc;ncias para o adquirente e para o incorporador e, assim, traz mais seguran&ccedil;a jur&iacute;dica &agrave;s suas rela&ccedil;&otilde;es e para a economia do pa&iacute;s, t&atilde;o sens&iacute;vel aos reflexos do cen&aacute;rio imobili&aacute;rio. A esse respeito, ali&aacute;s, al&eacute;m de certamente contribuir para a retomada do crescimento do mercado imobili&aacute;rio brasileiro, a convers&atilde;o do projeto em lei possivelmente resolver&aacute; milh&otilde;es de processos judiciais que tratam do tema e aguardam decis&atilde;o no Judici&aacute;rio, em especial porque, se aprovado, o projeto ir&aacute; ao encontro da jurisprud&ecirc;ncia que vem se formando em nossos tribunais.</p> <p>De acordo com o texto aprovado no Senado, o atraso de at&eacute; 180 dias para a entrega do im&oacute;vel n&atilde;o gerar&aacute; &ocirc;nus para a construtora. Se houver atraso maior na entrega das chaves, o comprador poder&aacute; desfazer o neg&oacute;cio e ter&aacute; direito a receber tudo o que pagou de volta, al&eacute;m da multa prevista em contrato, em at&eacute; 60 dias. Se n&atilde;o tiver multa prevista, o cliente ter&aacute; direito a 1% do valor j&aacute; desembolsado para cada m&ecirc;s de atraso.</p> <p>Al&eacute;m disso, permite que as construtoras fiquem com at&eacute; 50% dos valores pagos pelo consumidor em caso de desist&ecirc;ncia da compra, quando o empreendimento tiver seu patrim&ocirc;nio separado do da construtora (mecanismo chamado de patrim&ocirc;nio de afeta&ccedil;&atilde;o). Tal sistema foi criado ap&oacute;s a fal&ecirc;ncia da Encol, pois, com o patrim&ocirc;nio afetado, as parcelas pagas pelos compradores n&atilde;o se misturam ao patrim&ocirc;nio da incorporadora ou construtora e n&atilde;o poder&aacute; fazer parte da massa falida caso a empresa enfrente dificuldades financeiras. Para os demais casos, ou seja, fora do patrim&ocirc;nio de afeta&ccedil;&atilde;o, a multa prevista para o consumidor &eacute; de at&eacute; 25%.</p> <p>Al&eacute;m de regrar o limite da multa aplic&aacute;vel, o projeto aprovado tamb&eacute;m traz maior seguran&ccedil;a jur&iacute;dica ao prever que haver&aacute; o desconto da comiss&atilde;o de corretagem, dos impostos incidentes sobre o im&oacute;vel, de eventuais taxas de condom&iacute;nio e de esp&eacute;cie de aluguel, conforme valor previsto em contrato, ou se n&atilde;o houver essa previs&atilde;o, conforme valor fixado em ju&iacute;zo, caso a desist&ecirc;ncia ocorra ap&oacute;s o adquirente entrar no im&oacute;vel.</p> <p>A devolu&ccedil;&atilde;o do dinheiro para o adquirente ser&aacute; feita em parcela &uacute;nica at&eacute; 30 dias ap&oacute;s o habite-se do im&oacute;vel constru&iacute;do sob o regime de afeta&ccedil;&atilde;o (e n&atilde;o mais de forma imediata, como tem sido entendido pelos nossos tribunais) ou em at&eacute; 180 dias ap&oacute;s a assinatura do distrato, quando o im&oacute;vel n&atilde;o estiver submetido a tal regime.</p> <p>O projeto refor&ccedil;a a necessidade imediata de um norte regulat&oacute;rio sobre a desist&ecirc;ncia da compra de im&oacute;veis no pa&iacute;s. Os consumidores e as incorporadoras necessitam de uma maior seguran&ccedil;a jur&iacute;dica para realizar seus neg&oacute;cios e firmar os contratos.</p> <p>Autor: <strong>Gustavo Milar&eacute;</strong> &ndash; Advogado, mestre e doutor em Direito Processual Civil e s&oacute;cio do escrit&oacute;rio Meirelles Milar&eacute; Advogados</p> <p>Fonte: Conex&atilde;o Tocantins</p>'>
```

right now I wanna show into that iframe a gzip encoded html string!
how can I do it?

in php server: `gzcompress()`, `gzdeflate()`, or `gzencode()`?

what prefix should I use instead of `"data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"` ?

Comment: I think you need the defalte function. The data type should be the same, since the output will be text/html